# Cannot play AVI video

Tags: video, vlc, ffmpeg

I have an AVI video. I have tried it playing it with the standard Ubuntu "Video" application as well as VLC. It cannot be played.

The video has no problems as it can be played no problem in a windows system.

What should I modify to play this video with VLC or Video? Any customization? codec?

P.S. I have been suggested to "check the format with ffprobe"  but I don't know what that means? What is ffprobe?

EDIT:  As asked the results of ffprobe are

```
ffprobe version 4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2007-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=1ubuntu0.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-nvenc --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, avi, from 'fov120.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.17.101
  Duration: 00:08:17.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 18236 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (XVID / 0x44495658), yuv420p, 2306x1154 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1153:577], 18239 kb/s, 8 fps, 8 tbr, 8 tbn, 8 tbc
[STREAM]
index=0
codec_name=mpeg4
codec_long_name=MPEG-4 part 2
profile=Simple Profile
codec_type=video
codec_time_base=1/8
codec_tag_string=XVID
codec_tag=0x44495658
width=2306
height=1154
coded_width=2306
coded_height=1154
has_b_frames=0
sample_aspect_ratio=1:1
display_aspect_ratio=1153:577
pix_fmt=yuv420p
level=1
color_range=unknown
color_space=unknown
color_transfer=unknown
color_primaries=unknown
chroma_location=left
field_order=unknown
timecode=N/A
refs=1
quarter_sample=false
divx_packed=false
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=8/1
avg_frame_rate=8/1
time_base=1/8
start_pts=0
start_time=0.000000
duration_ts=3976
duration=497.000000
bit_rate=18239026
max_bit_rate=N/A
bits_per_raw_sample=N/A
nb_frames=3976
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=0
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
DISPOSITION:timed_thumbnails=0
[/STREAM]
[FORMAT]
filename=fov120.avi
nb_streams=1
nb_programs=0
format_name=avi
format_long_name=AVI (Audio Video Interleaved)
start_time=0.000000
duration=497.000000
size=1132946620
bit_rate=18236565
probe_score=100
TAG:encoder=Lavf58.17.101
[/FORMAT]
```

Comment: ffprobe is a media file info tool that comes with ffmpeg. Install the ffmpeg package and then run `ffprobe -show_streams -show_format video.avi`, then copy and paste all of the text.

Comment: @llogan  I edited with the results

Comment: Nothing special about it. Old, legacy MPEG-4 video. This file was made by ffmpeg. VLC should play it with no problem. What error do you get from your players? Does ffplay play it? Try `ffplay fov120.avi`

Comment: VLC cannot play it. I am playing it not from the console so I dont know what error I get. It just doesnt play. However `ffplay` does play it very well. Thanks for that! In the meantime I am going to use that, though the question is not solved.

Comment: @KansaiRobot vlc can play it from terminal as well and this will give some error messages: `cvlc -vv fov120.avi ` although ffplay might be enough?

Comment: @KansaiRobot Maybe it is a problem with hardware accelerated playback settings. Worth trying disabling/enabling it. See https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_HowTo/Hardware_acceleration/

Comment: @andrew.46  I have VLC installed but from the terminal `cvlc` is not installed for some reason. It says "install vlc-bin". Are they the same program?

Comment: Ubuntu / Debian split the source up for packaging. The package vlc-bin installs cvlc, nvlc, rvlc and vlc. So yes :)